# I'm trying to turn Nezuko (from Demon Slayer) into a Vampire in a Dark Ages setting. What would be the best build for such an NPC?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, vampire-the-dark-ages, vampire-20th-anniversary

So I'm trying to turn Nezuko, from Demon Slayer, into a Vampire in a setting in the Dark Ages. She's basically Nezuko but transplanted to another setting. I'm currently using "Vampire the Masquerade - Dark Ages 20th Anniversary edition" and don't want to use anything beyond that.

As a result if I was to turn her into a Vampire, as that's the point of this exercise, what be the best build to have for her and if so why? I want to keep her as intact as possible whilst making her a Vampire.

I'm a total newbie at this game and thus would greatly request assistance on helping me on this matter.

[The Demon Slayer Wiki page for Nezuko](https://kimetsu-no-yaiba.fandom.com/wiki/Nezuko_Kamado) summarises a lot of information about her including her personality, but the key points are:

- Nezuko was an eldest sister before becoming a demon. Although she straddles the line between monster and human, she seems to be lucid just enough that she's still there, and is caring and protective towards others, going up to fiercely defensive when someone's in danger.
- She's a fast and powerful combatant, possessing claws, fangs, and considerable brute strength.
- She's developed a blood control art: she seems to be able to ignite, soldify, and fluidly control her own blood and sometimes that of others.
- She can also change size, ranging between a younger version of herself or a taller adult version.
- Nezuko sleeps *instead of* consuming humans (including their blood) like demons are supposed to. As a result, she spends most of her time sleeping, using her size change ability to fit into a carryable box.

Comment: Please add what the character's powerset, personality and traits are like, those inform about the best clan to match

Comment: I've revised the enormous wiki quote down to a summary drawing on my own knowledge of the show & what would be important to consider & capture in a character build. Like most adaptation type questions though, this is probably going to be best answered by those already familiar with Demon Slayer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Things that need to go

All Vampires in Vampire **need** to drink blood. There is **no** way to get around drinking blood. Also, no vampire can sustain sunlight at all for an extended time. Neither part can be done.

### Disciplines required

> fast and powerful combatant, possessing claws, fangs, and considerable brute strength

Fangs are automatic. Claws are gained from Protean or Vicissitude. Potence gives you strength beyond human measure.

> She can change size

This is a staple of Vicissitude.

> She's developed a blood control art

This is Thaumaturgy. There are many paths, you might need to ask your GM what might fit best.

### Which Clan?

So, we need a clan that has Potence and Vicissitude. Potence is a *common* discipline, so anyone can take it.

- Tzimisce get Animalism, Auspex, Vicissitude.

They are the **only** ones that get Vicissitude, and they are not called Fiends for no reason: they shape their bodies into monsters, manipulate humans into beasts and breed Ghouls to create bloodlines of natural-Ghouls. They also possess Kholdunic Sorcery, a version of Thaumaturgy. So that is the best match but for the personality.

If you skip body shaping and thaumaturgy, you can take the following:

- Anda get Animalism, Fortitude, Protean
- Gangrel get Animalism, Fortitude, Protean

Both are very much related, but neither has its own Thaumaturgy path. You'd need to skip on Blood control for the start and find a teacher in the game.

### Non-Vampire NPCs using Vampire Stats?

There's a time-honored tradition to emulate non-vampire beasts with vampire statistics. However, then the idea of clan is discarded, and they get instead just the fitting statistics. For example, the Werewolf can be found in the main line corebook.<sup>1</sup> Powers of those adversaries are usually explained using the own splat's powers as explainer, but could be replaced with the proper stats from the game line they stem from if you want crossover.

Dark Ages does not have Werewolves in the back chapter, but only True Faith (Inquisition), Animals, Demons and Ghosts. So it *does* explicitly have a chapter to model actual Demons as Demons.<sup>2</sup>

These Demons follow *mostly* the Werewolf Spirit rules when it comes to setup. Why? Because (these) Demons are technically Spirits, the very same that Werewolves summon. They get powers in the shape of Charms, innate powers that at times mimic specific powers of Disciplins.

### Page references

1 - Vampire the Masquerade 20th Anniversary Edition, p. 378-379.
2 - Vampire the Dark Ages 20th Anniversary Edition, p.400-402.

Comment: I note the question says this character will be an NPC, so character creation and building rules don’t really need to apply. Does that revise your answer?

Comment: Actually it would help if you consider it as pc as well.

Comment: @GuybrushMcKenzie added